# How do you create a debug only function that takes a variable argument list? Like printf()

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'd like to make a debug logging function with the same parameters as `printf`.  But one that can be removed by the pre-processor during optimized builds.

For example:

```
Debug_Print("Warning: value %d > 3!\n", value);
```

I've looked at variadic macros but those aren't available on all platforms. `gcc` supports them, `msvc` does not.

Comment: Stu, MSVC does support variadic functions, it does not support variadic macros. Edit: My bad: Support for variadic macros was introduced in Visual C++ 2005.

Comment: See also [C `#define` macro for debug printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644868/c-define-macro-for-debug-printing).  Note, in particular, that it is generally best to ensure the compiler compiles (but optimizes away) the code from a debug macro, so that the code is always checked and hence always correct.  Otherwise, bit-rot can set in and when you reactivate the debug macro a decade later, you find that it no longer compiles.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I still do it the old way, by defining a macro (XTRACE, below) which correlates to either a no-op or a function call with a variable argument list. Internally, call vsnprintf so you can keep the printf syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void XTrace0(LPCTSTR lpszText)
{
   ::OutputDebugString(lpszText);
}

void XTrace(LPCTSTR lpszFormat, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, lpszFormat);
    int nBuf;
    TCHAR szBuffer[512]; // get rid of this hard-coded buffer
    nBuf = _vsnprintf(szBuffer, 511, lpszFormat, args);
    ::OutputDebugString(szBuffer);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Then a typical #ifdef switch:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define XTRACE XTrace
#else
#define XTRACE
#endif
```

Well that can be cleaned up quite a bit but it's the basic idea.

Comment: Excellent answer, but you should have used **_vsntprintf** to actually make it Unicode compatible.  I have added my own version, because I had a requirement to prepend a string (like [DEBUG]).  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39186784/912236

Comment: `_vsnprintf()` is specific to particular (Microsoft-compatible) implementations - and deprecated.  `vsnprintf()` is standard.

Comment: Why using `::` ?

Comment: @Konrad adding :: qualifies the function so that it is from global scope.

Comment: @pro-gramer yeah but only when you have function with the same name in local scope, so I see no reason to do that here.

Comment: The way the macro is defined, the argument list is not removed from the code when `_DEBUG` is not defined. You need to add a variadic argument list to the `XTRACE` macro and pass its contents through to the `XTrace()` function.

Answer (score 22):

This is how I do debug print outs in C++. Define 'dout' (debug out) like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dout cout
#else
#define dout 0 && cout
#endif
```

In the code I use 'dout' just like 'cout'.

```
dout << "in foobar with x= " << x << " and y= " << y << '\n';
```

If the preprocessor replaces 'dout' with '0 && cout' note that << has higher precedence than && and short-circuit evaluation of && makes the whole line evaluate to 0. Since the 0 is not used the compiler generates no code at all for that line.

Comment: I find the following modification useful: `#define dout cout << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << ") DEBUG: "`

Comment: In this case it will not be possible to use for example : `dout << setw(10) << "test";`

Comment: This generates warnings (gcc -Wall) when debug is not activated:

 "warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value] 0 && std::cout << "test";

Answer (score 11):

Here's something that I do in C/C++. First off, you write a function that uses the varargs stuff (see the link in Stu's posting). Then do something like this:

```
 int debug_printf( const char *fmt, ... );
 #if defined( DEBUG )
  #define DEBUG_PRINTF(x) debug_printf x
 #else
   #define DEBUG_PRINTF(x)
 #endif

 DEBUG_PRINTF(( "Format string that takes %s %s\n", "any number", "of args" ));
```

All you have to remember is to use double-parens when calling the debug function, and the whole line will get removed in non-DEBUG code.

Answer (score 5):

Ah, vsprintf() was the thing I was missing.  I can use this to pass the variable argument list directly to printf():

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void DBG_PrintImpl(char * format, ...)
{
    char buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
    printf("%s", buffer);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Then wrap the whole thing in a macro.

Answer (score 4):

Another fun way to stub out variadic functions is:

```
#define function sizeof
```

Answer (score 3):

@CodingTheWheel:

There is one slight problem with your approach. Consider a call such as

```
XTRACE("x=%d", x);
```

This works fine in the debug build, but in the release build it will expand to:

```
("x=%d", x);
```

Which is perfectly legitimate C and will compile and usually run without side-effects but generates unnecessary code. The approach I usually use to eliminate that problem is:

1. Make the XTrace function return an int (just return 0, the return value doesn't matter)
2. Change the #define in the #else clause to:

   ```
   0 && XTrace
   ```

Now the release version will expand to:

```
0 && XTrace("x=%d", x);
```

and any decent optimizer will throw away the whole thing since short-circuit evaluation would have prevented anything after the && from ever being executed.

Of course, just as I wrote that last sentence, I realized that perhaps the original form might be optimized away too and in the case of side effects, such as function calls passed  as parameters to XTrace, it might be a better solution since it will make sure that debug and release versions will behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you can use the streaming operator to simplify things:

```
#if defined _DEBUG

class Trace
{
public:
   static Trace &GetTrace () { static Trace trace; return trace; }
   Trace &operator << (int value) { /* output int */ return *this; }
   Trace &operator << (short value) { /* output short */ return *this; }
   Trace &operator << (Trace &(*function)(Trace &trace)) { return function (*this); }
   static Trace &Endl (Trace &trace) { /* write newline and flush output */ return trace; }
   // and so on
};

#define TRACE(message) Trace::GetTrace () << message << Trace::Endl

#else
#define TRACE(message)
#endif
```

and use it like:

```
void Function (int param1, short param2)
{
   TRACE ("param1 = " << param1 << ", param2 = " << param2);
}
```

You can then implement customised trace output for classes in much the same way you would do it for outputting to `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1):

What platforms are they not available on? stdarg is part of the standard library:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdarg.h.html

Any platform not providing it is not a standard C implementation (or very, very old). For those, you will have to use varargs:

http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/varargs.h.html

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8(VS.71).aspx -- For the record, this article even shows you how to use the old-school varargs as a bonus.

Comment: Looks like support for variadic macros was introduced in Visual C++ 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem with this kind of functionality is that often it requires
variadic macros.  These were standardized fairly recently(C99), and lots of
old C compilers do not support the standard, or have their own special work
around.

Below is a debug header I wrote that has several cool features:

- Supports C99 and C89 syntax for debug macros
- Enable/Disable output based on function argument
- Output to file descriptor(file io)

Note: For some reason I had some slight code formatting problems.

```
#ifndef _DEBUG_H_
#define _DEBUG_H_
#if HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif

#include "stdarg.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#define ENABLE 1
#define DISABLE 0

extern FILE* debug_fd;

int debug_file_init(char *file);
int debug_file_close(void);

#if HAVE_C99
#define PRINT(x, format, ...) \
if ( x ) { \
if ( debug_fd != NULL ) { \
fprintf(debug_fd, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} \
else { \
fprintf(stdout, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} \
}
#else
void PRINT(int enable, char *fmt, ...);
#endif

#if _DEBUG
#if HAVE_C99
#define DEBUG(x, format, ...) \
if ( x ) { \
if ( debug_fd != NULL ) { \
fprintf(debug_fd, "%s : %d " format, __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} \
else { \
fprintf(stderr, "%s : %d " format, __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} \
}

#define DEBUGPRINT(x, format, ...) \
if ( x ) { \
if ( debug_fd != NULL ) { \
fprintf(debug_fd, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} \
else { \
fprintf(stderr, format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
} \
}
#else /* HAVE_C99 */

void DEBUG(int enable, char *fmt, ...);
void DEBUGPRINT(int enable, char *fmt, ...);

#endif /* HAVE_C99 */
#else /* _DEBUG */
#define DEBUG(x, format, ...)
#define DEBUGPRINT(x, format, ...)
#endif /* _DEBUG */

#endif /* _DEBUG_H_ */
```

Comment: It seems odd to use '`debug_fd`' to hold a file pointer rather than a file descriptor; it would be more conventional to use '`debug_fp`'.

Comment: The ##__VA_ARGS__ is awesome! didn't know about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread:

- [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/)

It should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Having come across the problem today, my solution is the following macro:

```
    static TCHAR __DEBUG_BUF[1024];
    #define DLog(fmt, ...)  swprintf(__DEBUG_BUF, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__); OutputDebugString(__DEBUG_BUF);
```

You can then call the function like this:

```
    int value = 42;
    DLog(L"The answer is: %d\n", value);
```

Comment: I love it! Great solution and this should be accepted answer
Btw, you forgot a ; after declaring __DEBUG_BUF

Comment: This is a bad solution because it will overrun the supplied buffer without any warning. Do not use functions like `sprintf()` without proving that you have allocated the buffer to fit, first. The correct approach is to either use the `asprintf()` family, or to implement `asprintf()` yourself by using `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
inline void DPRINTF(int level, char *format, ...)
{
#    ifdef _DEBUG_LOG
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        if(debugPrint & level) {
                vfprintf(stdout, format, args);
        }
        va_end(args);
#    endif /* _DEBUG_LOG */
}
```

which costs absolutely nothing at run-time when the _DEBUG_LOG flag is turned off.

Comment: This will generate warnings for unused parameters in the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a TCHAR version of user's answer, so it will work as ASCII (*normal*), or Unicode mode (more or less).

```
#define DEBUG_OUT( fmt, ...) DEBUG_OUT_TCHAR(       \
            TEXT(##fmt), ##__VA_ARGS__ )
#define DEBUG_OUT_TCHAR( fmt, ...)                  \
            Trace( TEXT("[DEBUG]") #fmt,            \
            ##__VA_ARGS__ )
void Trace(LPCTSTR format, ...)
{
    LPTSTR OutputBuf;
    OutputBuf = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,   \
            (size_t)(4096 * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int nBuf;
    _vstprintf_s(OutputBuf, 4095, format, args);
    ::OutputDebugString(OutputBuf);
    va_end(args);
    LocalFree(OutputBuf); // tyvm @sam shaw
}
```

*I say, "more or less", because it won't automatically convert ASCII string arguments to WCHAR, but it should get you out of most Unicode scrapes without having to worry about wrapping the format string in TEXT() or preceding it with L.*

Largely derived from [MSDN: Retrieving the Last-Error Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680582(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: hey, you forget to use localfree api and will cause the memory leak.  And even you free it, it's not a good idea to use heap for this case.

Comment: @SamShaw well spotted, I also appended a notice disclaiming any further responsibility by pointing out it's MSDN origins.  Are you suggesting heap is bad because we could be logging a failure to allocate()?  I can't argue with that, since as I was writing the above code, I realised our existing Logger was getting information from the registry, and went a little insane... *postnote: my kingdom for a VS macro that will give me the TCHAR version of any given <string.h> function*

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what's asked in the question . But this code will be helpful for debugging purposes , it will print each variable's value along with it's name . This is completely type independent and supports variable number of arguments.
And can even display values of STL's nicely , given that you overload output operator for them

```
#define show(args...) describe(#args,args);
template<typename T>
void describe(string var_name,T value)
{
    clog<<var_name<<" = "<<value<<" ";
}

template<typename T,typename... Args>
void describe(string var_names,T value,Args... args)
{
    string::size_type pos = var_names.find(',');
    string name = var_names.substr(0,pos);
    var_names = var_names.substr(pos+1);
    clog<<name<<" = "<<value<<" | ";
    describe(var_names,args...);
}
```

Sample Use :

```
int main()
{
    string a;
    int b;
    double c;
    a="string here";
    b = 7;
    c= 3.14;
    show(a,b,c);
}
```

Output :

```
a = string here | b = 7 | c = 3.14
```