# How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)

Tags: c, g++, c-preprocessor, variadic

I want to write a macro in C that accepts any number of parameters, not a specific number

example:

```
#define macro( X )  something_complicated( whatever( X ) )
```

where `X` is any number of parameters

I need this because `whatever` is overloaded and can be called with 2 or 4 parameters.

I tried defining the macro twice, but the second definition overwrote the first one!

The compiler I'm working with is g++ (more specifically, mingw)

Comment: Do you want C or C++? If you're using C, why are you compiling with a C++ compiler? To use proper C99 variadic macros, you should be compiling with a C compiler that supports C99 (like gcc), not a C++ compiler, since C++ doesn't have standard variadic macros.

Comment: Well, I assumed C++ is a super set of C in this regard ..

Comment: http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC13 has a detailed explanation of variadic macros.

Comment: A good explanation and example is here [http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Comment: For future readers: C is **not** a subest of C++. They share many many things, but there are rules that stop them being subset and superset of each other.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html
Here is a detailed explanation for variadic-macros

Answer (score 355, accepted):

C99 way:

```
#define FOO(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: I don't think C99 requires the ## before __VA_ARGS__. That might just be VC++.

Comment: The reason for ## before __VA_ARGS__ is that it swallows the preceding comma in case the variable-argument list is empty, eg. FOO("a") expands to printf("a"). This is an extension of gcc (and vc++, maybe), C99 requires at least one argument to be present in place of the ellipsis.

Comment: `##` is not needed and is not portable. `#define FOO(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)` does the job the portable way; the `fmt` parameter can be omitted from the definition.

Comment: IIRC, the ## is GCC specific and allows passing of zero parameters

Comment: What if you wanted to consume those arguments in the macro and without using printf or other functions that take variable args?

Comment: @Alek: If I use the portable FOO(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__) you suggest above, how would one add a "\n" except writing it in the macro call FOO("My string here\n")?

Comment: The ##-syntax works also with llvm/clang and the Visual Studio compiler. So it might not be portable, but it is supported by the major compilers.

Comment: @jjxtra I imagine you would need to pass them to one of your own functions that takes variable params.

Comment: @K.Biermann Even for compilers that **do** support `##`, if there's no comma *immediately before* the `##` in the macro, the `##` will try to *paste tokens together*, which is almost never the right behavior.

Answer (score 51):

`__VA_ARGS__` is the standard way to do it. Don't use compiler-specific hacks if you don't have to.

C++ is not a superset of C. It is really silly to compile your C code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: *"It is really silly to compile your C code with a C++ compiler"* => Not considered so by everyone (including me).  See for instance C++ core guidelines:  **CPL.1: Prefer C++ to C** , [**CPL.2: If you must use C, use the common subset of C and C++, and compile the C code as C++**](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rcpl-subset).  I'm hard-pressed to think of what "C-only-isms" one really needs to make it worth not programming in the compatible subset, and the C and C++ committees have worked hard on making that compatible subset available.

Comment: @HostileFork Fair enough, though *of course* the C++ folks would like to encourage use of C++. Others do disagree, though; Linux Torvalds, for instance, has apparently rejected multiple proposed Linux-kernel patches that attempt to replace the identifier `class` with `klass` to permit compiling with a C++ compiler. Also note that there are some differences that will trip you up; for instance, the ternary operator is not evaluated in the same way in both languages, and the `inline` keyword means something completely different (as I learned from a different question).

Comment: For really cross-platform systems projects like an operating system, you really want to adhere to strict C, because C compilers are so much more common. In embedded systems, there are still platforms without C++ compilers. (There are platforms with only passable C compilers!) C++ compilers make me nervous, particularly for cyber-physical systems, and I would guess I'm not the only embedded software / C programmer with that feeling.

Comment: @downbeat Whether you use C++ for production or not, if it's rigor you are concerned about, then being able to compile with C++ gives you magic powers for static analysis.  If you have a query you want to make of a C codebase...wondering about if certain types are used certain ways, learning how to use [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) can build targeted tools for it.  What you'd pay big bucks for a static analysis tool of C to do can be done with a bit of C++ know how and the compiler you already have...

Comment: I'm speaking to the question of Linux. (I just noticed that it says "Linux Torvalds" ha!)

Comment: There's nothing "magic" about type_traits.  C has similar stuff, such as "typeof."  Yes, technically it is a compiler extension, but both gcc and clang support it.  Neither typeof nor type_traits are replacements for static analysis tools (many of which are free

Comment: @HostileForksaysdonttrustSE is there a standard or specification for the "compatible subset".

Answer (score 32):

I don't think that's possible, you could fake it with double parens ... just as long you don't need the arguments individually.

```
#define macro(ARGS) some_complicated (whatever ARGS)
// ...
macro((a, b, c))
macro((d, e))
```

Comment: While it is possible to have a variadic macro, using double parenthesis is a good advice.

Comment: The XC compiler by Microchip does not support variadic macros, and so this double parenthesis trick is the best you can do.

Answer (score 13):

```
#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
  #define PRINT print
#else
  #define PRINT(...) ((void)0) //strip out PRINT instructions from code
#endif 

void print(const char *fmt, ...) {

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsprintf(str, fmt, args);
        va_end(args);

        printf("%s\n", str);

}

int main() {
   PRINT("[%s %d, %d] Hello World", "March", 26, 2009);
   return 0;
}
```

If the compiler does not understand variadic macros, you can also strip out PRINT with either of the following:

```
#define PRINT //
```

or

```
#define PRINT if(0)print
```

The first comments out the PRINT instructions, the second prevents PRINT instruction because of a NULL if condition. If optimization is set, the compiler should strip out never executed instructions like: if(0) print("hello world"); or ((void)0);

Comment: #define PRINT // will not replace PRINT with //

Comment: #define PRINT if(0)print is not a good idea either because the calling code might have its own else-if for calling PRINT. Better is: #define PRINT if(true);else print

Comment: The standard "do nothing, gracefully" is do {} while(0)

Comment: The proper `if` version of "don't do this" that takes code structure into account is: `if (0) { your_code } else` a semi-colon after your macro expansion terminates the `else`.  The `while` version looks like: `while(0) { your_code }`  The issue with the `do..while` version is that the code in `do { your_code } while (0)` is done once, guaranteed.  In all three cases, if `your_code` is empty, it is a proper `do nothing gracefully`.

Answer (score 10):

explained for g++ here, though it is part of C99 so should work for everyone

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_44.html

quick example:

```
#define debug(format, args...) fprintf (stderr, format, args)
```

Comment: GCC's variadic macros are not C99 variadic macros. GCC _has_ C99 variadic macros, but G++ doesn't support them, because C99 is not part of C++.

Comment: Actually g++ will compile C99 macros in C++ files. It will issue a warning, however, if compiled with '-pedantic'.

Comment: It is not C99. C99 use __VA_ARGS__ macro).

Comment: Wrong, __VA_ARGS__ is standard.

Comment: C++11 also supports `__VA_ARGS__`, although they are supported by compilers in earlier versions as well, as an extension.

Comment: This fails to work for printf("hi"); where there are no var args.  Any generic way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

• Variable number of arguments is denoted by an ellipsis (...)
• The syntax of ISO C requires at least one fixed argument before the ‘...’

For example, you can type:

```
#define DEBUGMSG ( int, ...)
```