# C++ macro with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/c-c-how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)

I need macro that will expand in a array that contains it's arguments. For example:

```
#define foo(X0) char* array[1] = {X0}
#define foo(X0, X1) char* array[2] = {X0, X1}
```

and so on. My problem is that I need to use foo with variable number of arguments, so I want to be able to use foo("foo0") but also to use foo("foo0", "foo1", "foo2"..."fooN"). I know it's possible to have:

```
#define foo(...)
#define foo_1(X0) ..
#define foo_2(X0, X1) ..
#define foo_3(X0, X1, X2) ..
#define foo_N(X0, X1, ... XN) ..
```

And use ____VA_ARGS____, but I don't know how may I expand foo in foo_k macro depending on it's parameter count? Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked into: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Comment: I don't want boost. It's to heavy to carry in a small project!

Comment: I didn't know that __VA_ARGS__ expand also the commas:). Stupid me:)

Comment: so is libstd, however you don't carry it with you, you require it as a dependencies.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about:

```
#define FOO( ... ) char* x[] = { __VA_ARGS__ };
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
#define foo(args...) char* array[] = {args}
```

Note that this uses a GNU extension and so will only work with gcc and gcc-compatible compilers. @JoeSlav's answer using `__VA_ARGS__` is more portable.

Comment: #define foo(...) char* array[] = {__VA_ARGS__}

Comment: I think this should be marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [gcc.gnu.org docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) on the subject.

Or you could jump straight away to this answer:

[How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/c-c-how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments/679993#679993)