# Parentheses and macro overloading in C++

Tags: c++, macros

My codebase has an existing macro:

```
#define SOME_MACRO <macro definition>
```

For some changes I'm making, I want to add a new version of the macro that takes an argument.

```
#define SOME_MACRO(arg1) <macro definition>
```

I see that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683146/can-macros-be-overloaded-by-number-of-arguments?rq=1) addresses selecting from multiple argument versions of a macro. However, the SOME_MACRO call does not already have parantheses. It's used as SOME_MACRO, not SOME_MACRO(). Is there any way to implement macro overloading such that SOME_MACRO calls SOME_MACRO(). I tried:

```
#define SOME_MACRO SOME_MACRO()
#define SOME_MACRO(...) <macro definition using __VA_ARGS__>
```

but that just got me a macro redefinition error. At the call site, this is what it currently looks like:

```
SOME_MACRO << "This is a test";
```

I want to add new calls of the form:

```
SOME_MACRO(foo) << "This is a test";
```

I want both calls to work, since the former is already in the code base. These are basically logging macros, and they create objects that expose a stream. On destruction, they write out the stream contents.

Comment: You *can't* "overload" macros, it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro overloading is not possible.
In your case since you don't want `SOME_MACRO` anymore once the `SOME_MACRO(...)` is defined, you may do following in the intended (header) file:

```
#undef SOME_MACRO  // hopefully it is not a standard macro!
#define SOME_MACRO(...) // use __VA_ARGS__
```

Now in the code you can call `SOME_MACRO(x,y,z)`; i.e. with parenthesis.

In case if you want to retain `SOME_MACRO` as it is in the code, then do as following:

```
#undef SOME_MACRO
#define SOME_MACRO SOME_MACRO_1(<pass arguments here itself>)
```

Remember that the arguments passed above will be as it is everywhere.

Comment: @iammilind I updated the question with more details of what the call sites look like. Since I want the original call site to also work we can't undef SOME_MACRO can we?

Comment: @theraju, unfortunately what you ask is overloading of macro and that's not possible. You have to make a choice between either of them.