# MSVC Preprocessor Bug - Overloading C/C++ Macro on Argument Count

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, preprocessor, variadic-macros

I'm trying to write an overloaded macro to format `StringMap` entries, and cannot get the preprocessor to recognize when there is more than 1 argument. I have looked at virtually all similar questions and have tried 5+ implementations but none work. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683146/can-macros-be-overloaded-by-number-of-arguments?lq=1).

My implementation is identical to the accepted answer, as follows:

```
#define STRING_MAP_ENTRY_1(a) \
  { a, #a }
#define STRING_MAP_ENTRY_2(a, b) \
  { a, b }

#define STRING_MAP_ENTRY( ... ) VA_SELECT( STRING_MAP_ENTRY, __VA_ARGS__ )
#define CAT( A, B ) A ## B
#define SELECT( NAME, NUM ) CAT( NAME ## _, NUM )

#define GET_COUNT( _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, COUNT, ... ) COUNT
#define VA_SIZE( ... ) GET_COUNT( __VA_ARGS__, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 )

#define VA_SELECT( NAME, ... ) SELECT( NAME, VA_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__) )(__VA_ARGS__)
```

This works for a single argument call such as `enum strings` below, but for `manual_strings` I get the warning `warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'STRING_MAP_ENTRY_1'`. Which tells me it's not working properly because it's not calling the `_2` version.

```
static StringMap<uint8> const enum_strings = {
    STRING_MAP_ENTRY(ENUM_VALUE_1),
    STRING_MAP_ENTRY(ENUM_VALUE_2)};

static StringMap<uint8> const manual_strings = {
    STRING_MAP_ENTRY(0, "ENTRY_0"),
    STRING_MAP_ENTRY(1, "ENTRY_1")};
```

I get this same warning trying every other implementation I've seen in similar questions on SO. Any idea why it's not working? I've seen a lot of notes here and there referring to compiler versions. Could this be the cause? The project is compiled using default MSVC compiler from VS 2017. I have included the C tag because, although this is in C++, the macro definitions are all valid C.

Comment: Did you read the C11 standard [n1570](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~vlado/pl/C_Standard_2011-n1570.pdf) and the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) ? C and C++ are *different* programming languages

Comment: You could also consider *generating* your C or C++ code, perhaps using [GPP](https://github.com/logological/gpp/) or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)

Comment: MSVC preprocessor is known to be quirky, it's probably one of its bugs.

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch - I'm not sure what you mean, obviously I understand they're different languages. I just noted that the macro implementations are valid in both languages.

Comment: FYI, `StringMap<uint8>` is invalid syntax for C language.  Are you really programming in C?  Update your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, did you read the last part of the question? I noted that I tagged C because the macros (and the answer for the macro implementation) are all valid C.

Comment: Use `@username` when replying, otherwise they won't get the notifications.

Comment: Microsoft's compiler is broken, news at 9.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/460154/-va-args-seems-to-be-trated-as-a-single-parameter.html