# can I have a C macro that accepts undefined number of parameters?

Tags: c, logging, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)

I want to have a log macro in basic C which accepts arguments similar to `printf` and logs them.  However, I want how it's logged (log level, file vs `stderr`, etc.) to be something set at compile time, not runtime; with the method doing nothing and hopefully being optimized out of the code if I set parameters to ignore low level logging.

So far I have a macro which is defined based off of a parameter defined at compile time. If the parameter is defined logging goes to my log method (to log to files) otherwise it goes to `stderr`.  However, I can only pass a string into this macro.  The log method is capable of taking an indefinite number of arguments and works using `printf` syntax.  I want to know if there is a way to set my macro up so it will pass an indefinite number of arguments to the log file?

And since I suspect the answer is that I can't do that is there another method of achieving what I want in basic C (I can't use C++ or boost).

Answer (score 7):

C99 have macros that can accept a variable number of arguments. They are called *variadic macros*.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Example:

```
#define eprintf(...) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#define dfprintf(stream, ...) fprintf(stream, "DEBUG: " __VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. C99 supports this [out of the box](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_44.html).

The syntax looks like:

`#define debug(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, ## __VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 0):

See Q10.26 from the comp.lang.c FAQ: [How can I write a macro which takes a variable number of arguments, or use the preprocessor to "turn off" a function call with a variable number of arguments?](http://www.c-faq.com/cpp/varargs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ellipsis to define a macro which takes a variable number of arguments:

```
#define debug(format, ...) fprintf (stderr, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_the_GNU_Compiler_Collection/variadic-macros.html