# C++ macro with a variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, macros

I would like to know how can I create a c++ macro that would make an or between a given number of arguments, something like

```
#define aMacro(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4) arg1==arg2 || arg1==arg3 || arg1==arg4
```

But with a varible number of arguments.

I know about varadic macros, I know they exist and I know there are some questions about it on SO but as far as I know none of them addresses my question on how to do the || part.

Thank you

Comment: Note that C++11 supports variadic macros with `__VA_ARGS__`.  See also [Boost Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor) for ways to handle loops on variable numbers of arguments.  Also note that for safety, the body of the macro in the question should be `((arg1) == (arg2) || (arg1) == (arg3) || (arg1) == (arg4))` or you're vulnerable to being invoked with odd-ball expressions that completely mangle the meaning of your code. Parenthesize each argument in a macro expansion (until you know enough to know when it isn't 100% necessary).

Comment: tip: try to avoid macros if you can

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall It's not a duplicate since the post you mentioned doesnt say how to make the or part.

Comment: @claptrap why should I avoid it? I think in this case It will make my code more readable because it will replace a quite verbose expression that appears in my code many times.

Comment: @Mppl because in C++ there is little reason to use macros when you have inline functions etc to your disposal. If you do not need to write portable code with conditional compilation then it can be avoided.

Comment: Do people actually read questions before voting to close them as duplicates?  Or do they simply scan for similar key words?

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro), what you're looking for is a variadic macro:

> A variadic macro is a feature of some computer programming languages,
>   especially the C preprocessor, whereby a macro may be declared to
>   accept a varying number of arguments.
>
> Variable-argument macros were introduced in 1999 in the ISO/IEC
>   9899:1999 (C99) revision of the C language standard, and in 2011 in
>   ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (C++11) revision of the C++ language standard.

So it is available in C++11 or in C99. It is available as en extension on some compiler too, for example GNU GCC supports it, and I think I read that VC++ too.

Then for the syntax, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments) post for example, which gives a straightforward example:

```
#define FOO(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, he doesn't want to invoke `printf()`; he wants to generate code that compares the first argument with each of the remaining arguments in turn.  You've not shown how to do that yet.

Comment: That precisely my problem I know how to Make a variadic macro, the hard part for me is to make the or like I mentioned

Comment: I still cant figure out how, could you give me an examples on how to do it please?

Comment: #define FOO(HEAD) HEAD
#define FOO(HEAD, ...) HEAD || FOO(##__VA_ARGS__)

Comment: Macros don't work that way.  The second definition of `FOO` destroys the first.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminLindley, I didn't know. Then we can test the __VA_ARGS__ and make a conditional call

Comment: @Geoffroy: Do you have the code for that?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley have a look at this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/d-6Mj5Lko_s

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, you're open to a vastly superior alternative to macros here that perhaps you weren't aware of.  This uses [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), which requires C++11. But if you want variadic macros, that requires C++11 as well.

```
template<typename T>
bool func(T const&)
{
    return false;
}

template<typename L, typename R, typename... Args>
bool func(L const& lhs, R const &rhs, Args const&... args)
{
    return (lhs == rhs) || func(lhs,args...);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to mention C++11?  I think you need to explain the ... notations.

Comment: He wanted `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: As far as I know varadic macros have some supoort from some major compilers even when not using c++11... Is this varadic templates thing supported when not using c++11 too?

Comment: Not as far as I know.