# mupdf - erroneous macro

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros, mupdf

I'm trying to compile [mupdf](http://www.mupdf.com/) on Windows 7 using mingw gcc. It is taking exception with the following line in [context.h](http://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/source/browse/trunk/mupdf/include/mupdf/fitz/context.h)

```
#define fz_throw(CTX, ERRCODE, MSG, ...) fz_throw_imp(CTX, __FILE__, __LINE__, ERRCODE, MSG, __VA_ARGS__)
```

With the error:

```
\mupdf\include/mupdf/fitz/context.h:70:105: error: expected expression before ')' token
```

Supposedly this code compiles with gcc. What is the particular issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

[How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)

Comment: Adding prefixing ## to __VA_ARGS__ in the macro resolved the issue. Thanks.