# How to use gettext with __VA_ARGS__ in c

Tags: c, gettext

I'm trying to translate my console log with gettext, but I get the follow error:

```
program.c: In function ‘program_take_screenshot’:
program.c:55:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘dcgettext’
 #define _(x) gettext(x)
              ^
program_logger.h:117:49: note: in definition of macro ‘PROGRAM_ERR’
       fprintf(LOG_FILE, "Program [ERROR] :: " __VA_ARGS__); \
                                                 ^
program.c:173:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘_’
       PROGRAM_ERR(_("Cannot take screenshot. GPU rendering is used and read_viewport is not supported.\n"));
                 ^
```

what I do wrong?

definition in program_logger.h:

```
#define PROGRAM_LOG(...) do { \
      if (PROGRAM_LOG_VERBOSE) \
      { \
         fprintf(LOG_FILE, "Program: " __VA_ARGS__); \
         fflush(LOG_FILE); \
      } \
   } while (0)
```

definition of PROGRAM_ERR:

```
#define PROGRAM_ERR(...) do { \
      fprintf(LOG_FILE, "PROGRAM [ERROR] :: " __VA_ARGS__); \
      fflush(LOG_FILE); \
   } while (0)
```

Comment: Also see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although one of the other answers explains what's going on, it doesn't give you an appropriate means of solving the problem.

What you had:

```
#define PROGRAM_ERR(...) do { \
      fprintf(LOG_FILE, "PROGRAM [ERROR] :: " __VA_ARGS__); \
      fflush(LOG_FILE); \
   } while (0)
```

would allow, for example, using it like `PROGRAM_ERR("some error: %s", "error message")`. Yet as you've found, `PROGRAM_ERR(_("some error: %s"), "error message")` fails.

The cause is, as explained already, indeed that this expands to

```
do { fprintf(LOG_FILE, "PROGRAM [ERROR] :: " _("some error: %s"), "error message"); fflush(LOG_FILE); } while(0)
```

and string concatenation only works for string literals.

In my opinion, the simplest way to make this work, is

```
#define PROGRAM_ERR(...) do { \
      fputs("PROGRAM [ERROR] :: ", LOG_FILE); \
      fprintf(LOG_FILE, __VA_ARGS__); \
      fflush(LOG_FILE); \
   } while (0)
```

By separating the two strings, you don't need any compile-time string concatenation, which is simply not possible if the strings are not known at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the macro to put `##` before `__VA_ARGS__`. (`##__VA_ARGS__`) That instructs the preprocessor to place a comma there, but only if there is an argument.

See the gcc documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) for more details.