# Standard way for writing a debug mode in C++

Tags: c++, debugging

Is there a "best practice" or similar for coding in a debug-mode in one's code?
For example,

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    #ifdef MY_DEBUG_DEF
    std::cout << "This is only printed if MY_DEBUG_DEF is defined\n";
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Or is this considered bad practice because the code gets bit messier?
I have noticed some libraries (for example libcurl, which is a large and well-known library) have this feature; if you define VERBOSE with libcurl you get basically a debug mode

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A more usual way is to follow conventions from [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html): wrap with `#ifndef NDEBUG` .... `#endif`code which is only useful for debugging, and without any significant side effects.

You could even add some debug-printing macro like

```
extern bool wantdebug;
#ifndef NDEBUG
#define OUTDEBUG(Out) do { if (wantdebug) \
   std::cerr << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ \
             << " " << Out << std::endl; \
} while(0)
#else
#define OUTDEBUG(Out) do {}while(0)
#endif
```

and use something like `OUTDEBUG("x=" << x)` at appropriate places in your code. Then `wantdebug` flag would be set thru the debugger, or thru some program arguments. You probably want to emit a newline and flush `cerr` (or `cout`, or your own debug output stream) -using `std::endl` ...-  to get the debug output displayed immediately (so a future crash of your program would still give sensible debug outputs).

Comment: That would make sense for `cout` (although I prefer to keep the unrelated actions of writing a newline and flushing a buffer separate; `endl` is so often misunderstood I just avoid it), but `cerr` has `unitbuf` set, so it flushes on every output operation anyway.

Comment: I still believe doing `endl` makes sense. You certainly want each debug message to be on its own line!

Answer (score 1):

That is an acceptable method. Yes, it gets messy, but it makes it a lot easier to debug as well. Plus you can normally collapse those kinds of things, thus removing the messiness.

As you've mentioned, libcurl uses the method. I also used to have a teacher who works for HP on their printer software, and they used the same method.

Comment: Okay, from your response I draw the conclusion that this is acceptable :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer runtime enabled logging. That means that you don't have to recompile to get the "debug output". So I have a command-line argument `-v=n`, where `n` defaults to zero, and gets stored in the variable `verbosity` in the actual program. With `-v=1` I get basic tracing (basic flow of the code), with `-v=2` I get "more stuff" (such as dumps of internal state in selected functions). Two levels is often enough, but three levels may be good at times. An alternative is to make `verbosity` a bit-pattern, and enable/disable certain functionality based on which bits are set - so set `bit 0` for basic trace, `bit 1` gives extra info in some module, bit 2 gives extra trace in another module, etc. If you want to be REALLY fancy, you have names, such as `-trace=all_basic`, `-trace=detailed`, `-trace=module_A`, `-trace=all_basic,module_A,module_B` or some such.

Combine this with a macro along the lines of:

```
 #define TRACE do { if (verbosity > 0) \ 
       std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" \
                 << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; } while(0)
```

For things that may take a substantial amount of extra time, such as verifying the correctness of a large and complex data structure (tree, linked list, etc), then using `#ifndef NDEBUG` around that code would be a good thing. Assuming of course you believe that you'll never mess that up in a release build.

Real livig code here:
https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/trace.h
https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/trace.cpp
being use here for example:
https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/expr.cpp

(Note that some simple functions that get called a lot don't have "TRACE" - it just clutters up the trace and makes it far too long)

Comment: I would suggest you remove the trailing `;` after `while(0)` so that you would write `TRACE;` and it's an instruction.

Comment: Indeed, that is what the linked source has - just simple typo when typing a different variant here...

Answer (score -1):

Using logger may be better, e.g.

- [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/)
- [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/)
- [ACE_Log_Msg](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/6.3.1/html/libace-doc/a00344.html): It is in [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html)
- [Boost.Log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0_b1/libs/log/doc/html/index.html):

The above are very flexible, but heavyweight. You can also implement some simple macros instead:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define DBG(FMT, ...)
#else // !NDEBUG
#define DBG(FMT, ...) fprintf (stderr, FMT, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#endif // NDEBUG
```

The above is GCC syntax from [Macros with a Variable Number of Arguments.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html)
For VC, please see also [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)