# C macro with special variable arguments

Tags: c

I always write below code for debug purpose:

```
printf("%s:%d this is a string %s int %d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__,strval,intval);
```

Now since the first part (FUNCTION,LINE) is always used, so I wish to create a macro to do it and just append other debug strings.

Maybe looks like:

```
#define MYPRINT(args...) printf("%s:%d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);printf(##args)
```

But I wish to use one statement rather than two as above! Is it possible?

### Clarify not duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)

This is different because I wish to add some new field into print command. actually answers here is great, thanks for all's help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)

Comment: Are you using GCC exclusively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a single call to `printf()`, your `MYPRINT` needs to be aware of a format string. You can try something like this, so long as the format string is a literal:

```
#define MYPRINT(FMT, ...) printf("%s:%d " FMT, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

The `##` is a GCC (and perhaps others) compiler extension that swallows the comma in the case `__VA_ARGS__` is actually empty. If your compiler does not support it, leave it off.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variadic macro and use `,` to have one statement:

```
#define MYPRINT(...) (printf("%s:%d",__FUNCTION__,__LINE__), printf(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: @Beatlej It's two function calls, but it is still an expression and not a compound statement. Again it has the slight advantage over the selected answer that you can use a string literal like this: `MYPRINT("hello world")` (you don't have to `MYPRINT("%s", "hello world")`.

Comment: Yes, the standard is missing a way to cleanly treat the variadic macro arguments as if they were variadic arguments to a function. The GCC extension does not care if variadic arguments are missing, but the standard requires at least one argument be present for the `...` in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYPRINT(fmt, ...) \
    printf("[%s]:%d - " fmt "\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    char const *s = "My string";
    int i = 42;
    MYPRINT("%s, %d", s, i);
}
```

Outputs :

```
[main]:8 - My string, 42
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but note that you cannot use a single argument with that macro definition, for example: `MYPRINT("Error!");` is not allowed.