# Macro auto-injecting argument without VARIADIC support

Tags: c++, c, unix, macros, c89

I have a macro with varargs that auto injects some arguments, like the first below injecting the argument "`__FNAME__`":

```
#ifdef VERBOSE
#define logdbg(format, ...) debugff(__FNAME__, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#elif defined(NORMAL)
#define logdbg(format, ...) debugf(format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define logdbg(format, ...) /* debud off */
#endif
```

But I need to keep this macro working with compilers without MACRO VARIADIC support (in SCO Unix and AIX 4.3 Copmiler v3).

In these environments I have now:

```
#ifdef VERBOSE
#define logdbg debugff(__FNAME__, format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#elif defined(NORMAL)
#define logdbg debugf
#else
#define logdbg if(1);else debugf
#endif
```

These compilers didn't accepted the comment in the last macro definition, and I get the `if(1);else blablabla` that works fine from https://stackoverflow.com/a/687412/926064

But I need yet a solution to the first case, where an argument is "injected" by macro.

Some workaround to do that ?

**EDIT:**

As it isn't a software with multithread support, I'm thinking to change the debug 'framework' to inject the arguments using side functions to set values in 'context' variables (global, static, etc):

```
#define logdbg pass_args(__FNAME__); debugf
```

More possibles workarounds ?

Comment: Side Note: `logdbg if(1);else debugf` looks like nothing good (you may wrap it into a `do { ... } while(0)`

Comment: Install a decent compiler on those platforms -- GCC for example.  It'll probably be quicker.  Note that the `##__VA_ARGS__` notation is already GCC-specific; it won't work with any other compiler.  Actually, come to that, `__FNAME__` is not standard C either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Installing others compilers isn't an option.

Comment: What about installing just a modern CPP (C preprocessor) and using that before compiling the code?  You're on a very sticky wicket.  The code is using a feature for which there is no counterpart in the oldest version of the standard, C89/C90.  It was a valuable addition in C99 because it allowed you to do things that could not be done before.

Comment: @DieterLücking "looks like nothing good"... Indeed. I think you may be slightly understating that. Just a bit...

Comment: @DieterLücking: (just re-posting the deleted comment): Cannot. There aren't Variadic support in macro.

Comment: That ellipses in my comment 'you may wrap it into a do { ... } while(0)' is something (nothing variadic)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Sorry, I didn't understand what you suggested. Wrapping isn't possible. The preprocessor cannot handle multiple arguments in macro, so I can only replace the name of the function preserving the args like in "#define log logfunc". So the real code "log(a1, a2, a3)", becomes "logfunc(a1, a2, a3)"

Comment: Is `__FNAME__` something you invented or is it part of your C preprocessor environment?  I consulted the GCC preprocessor [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/cpp/) and can't find a reference to `__FNAME__` -- and there's explicit mention that `, ##__VA_ARGS__` is a GNU extension.  Since names beginning with double-underscore are reserved for the implementation, you should not be using that name if you're defining it.

Comment: @jxh: But if(0) can generate problems in code like if(cond) logdbg() else xxx(). Preprocessed as: if(cond) if(0) logdbg() else xxx(), the else will be wrongly associated

Comment: @jonat: It's just a adopted snippet of code, and FNAME has another real name correctly prefixed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is ***impossible*** to use a different compiler (which seems a dubious requirement, but let's put that aside), for certain, you will need a different function for `logdbg` to expand into. Probably, that function would take the `__FNAME__` argument from another source, like a global variable.

```
#define logdbg ((logdbg_fname__ = __FNAME__), debugff_broken)

void debugff_broken(const char *fmt, ...) {
    extern const char *logdbg_fname__;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vdebugff(logdbg_fname__, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Where `vdebugff` is like `debugff` except it takes a `va_list`.

If thread safety is required, use thread specific storage instead of a common global.

Comment: You cannot change easily some policies and governance of some legacy environments to install or change everything in the system, as u do on your laptop. All you have is an old fashion vi and a 'resident' as-is C compiler and nothing more. Your approach is one I was working, but I need to ensure there is only one thread.

Comment: You can use thread specific storage from Solaris thread APIs or POSIX APIs. For compiler, you can compile the compiler as part of the build process, and not install it on the system.

Comment: Believe, we have a lot of restrictions including storage space in the work fs, since it's a production environment.

Comment: I am not sure I have seen a company unwilling to buy another disk for the build server before.

Comment: A company that's still using AIX 4.3.x is seriously stingy.  That's been obsolete (as in, completely out of support) for a decade or more (AIX 5.1 was out of support in 2006; IBM's web site no longer lists AIX 4.3 — I did find a reference to end of December 2003).  I'm not sure about the SCO Unix; it isn't clearly enough identified, but it too is likely to be rather old — hence the C89 compilers.

Comment: @jon: That's why we're fighting to do some improvement in a big legacy system to support an upgrade and replace about 40 servers spread over country. The lucky of them is I'm an engineer from 80s. Seriously, handle code with 25 years is exciting, mainly when some is yours (like a son)

Comment: It's an evil problem when code you wrote 25 years ago comes back to haunt you again.  Are you sure you wouldn't do better taking the code off the old machines, modernizing and testing it on the new ones, and then dealing with the data.  Leave the old and working code alone on the old and working (just) machines.  Do the upgrade in a modern environment.  All else apart, you'll be able to things a lot more quickly on the new machines.  You'll probably have orders of magnitude more memory and disk, maybe SSD too, and the CPU might also be most of an order of magnitude faster too.