# Trompeloeil MAKE_MOCK0 with a template as a return type

Tags: c++, trompeloeil

When using Trompeloeil to mock unit tests in C++, **how can use an `unordered_map` as a return type?**

```
// This example works fine
// return type is void, my_function takes no arguments 
MAKE_MOCK0(my_function, void(), override);


// This is what I'm trying to do but fails
MAKE_MOCK0(my_function, std::unordered_map<std::string, int>(), override);
```

Visual Studio is giving the following IntelliSense errors,

- [C2976](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2976?view=msvc-150) - `std::unordered_map`: too few template arguments
- [C2955](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2955?view=msvc-150) - `std::unordered_map`: use of class template requires template argument list
- [C2923](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2923?view=msvc-150) - `trompeloeil::param_list`: `std::_Hash<_Traits::size>` is not a valid template type argument for parameter type `T`
- [C2143](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2143?view=msvc-150) - syntax error missing `>` before `;`
- [C2955](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2955?view=msvc-150) - `trompeloeil::param_list` use of class template requires template argument list
- [C2338](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2338?view=msvc-150) - function signature does not have 0 parameters
- [C3203](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3203?view=msvc-150) - `unordered_map` unspecialized class can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'Sig', expected a real type
- [C4346](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4346?view=msvc-160) - `std::unordered_map::type` dependent name is not a type
- [C2923](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2923?view=msvc-150) - `trompeloeil::identity_type`: `std::unordered_map::type` is not a valid template type argument for parameter type `T`
- [C3203](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3203?view=msvc-150) - `unordered_map` unspecialized class can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T', expected a real type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templated return types need to be wrapped in `(...)`. This is explained in: [Q. Why can't I mock a function that returns a template?](https://github.com/rollbear/trompeloeil/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#return_template)

```
// Bad
MAKE_MOCK0(my_function, std::unordered_map<std::string, int>(), override);

// Good
MAKE_MOCK0(my_function, (std::unordered_map<std::string, int>()), override);
```

The C++ preprocessor may have an issue parsing the template with multiple parameters `std::string, int`. If this occurs, moving the return type to a typedef can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38030161/2601293

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, int> My_Type;
...
MAKE_MOCK0(my_function, (My_Type()), override);
```