# How can I create a Wrapper to a a Macro with variable number of arguments?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I have a macro like

```
LOG_I(_module, _message, ...)
```

I need to create a wrapper to this macro

```
#define WRAPPER_LOG(_module, _message, ...) LOG_I(_module, _message, ...)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can't create "*wrapper*s" to macros. They are not functions! Why do you need it?

Comment: We want to create a platform independent layer to Platform specific Macros so that when we move over to a newer platform, we do not need to change the code everywhere

Comment: So just `#ifdef PLATFORM_A #define LOG_I ...` and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments)

Comment: @apoorvn C is not C++.  Please pick a language.  C++ has things such as variadic templates and parameter packs, thus no need for macros.

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is not related to the C core-language, nor the other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if you did

```
#define WRAPPER_LOG(_module, _message, ...) LOG_I(_module, _message, __VA_ARGS__)
```

but whether it is what you *really* need, is another matter.