# How to define a macro that takes an arbitrary number of arguments and expands to give only the even arguments?

Tags: c, macros, variadic

Is it possible to define a variadic C macro that expand to give every other argument? In other words,

```
EVEN(A,a,B,b)
```

expands to

```
a, b
```

and

```
EVEN(A,a,B,b,C,c)
```

expands to

```
a, b, c
```

etc.

I can define one that takes a pre-determined number of arguments

```
#define EVEN(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6) a2, a4, a6
```

but how do you define a macro that takes an arbitrary number of arguments?

```
#define EVEN(args...)        ???
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments duplicate?

Comment: @IvanC — I don't think that explains how to do differential argument handling necessary to achieve the `EVEN` macro.  Yes, `__VA_ARGS__` figures in the solution.  You might need the GCC extension `## __VA_ARGS__` even.  But it doesn't explain the rest.

Comment: Some of the things one can do with the C preprocessor are pretty surprising, given its limitations, but I'm having trouble seeing how this would be one of them.

Comment: You would need a recursive macro for this, which is not possible.