# Generalized iteration over arguments of macro in the C preprocessor

Tags: c-preprocessor

There were several questions here regarding variadic macros in C. These include:

- [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments) which explains the basics, e.g., passing a variable number of arguments to functions such as `printf`
- [Is it possible to iterate over arguments in variadic macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macro),  which explains how to iteratively apply a macro to each of the arguments of the variadic macro.
- https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro which explains how to do so on pairs

My question is related to the iteration technique. I am interested in a macro with this generalized semantics.

```
ITERATE(Before, Action, Between, After, Empty, ...)
```

that will place `Before` prior to all expansions, apply `Action` to each argument, place `Between` between every two consecutive applications, and will finally place the expansion of `After`. Moreover, if the number of argument With such a macro, it should be possible to write

```
// Loop elements
#define A(x) (x) 
#define Befor (
#define After )
#define Between ||
#define Empty 1

// Define an OR macro
#define OR(...) ITERATE(Before, A, Between, Empty, __VA_ARGS__)

// Use it
OR()      // Expands to 1
OR(a)     // Expands to ((a))
OR(a,b)   // Expands to ((a)||(b))
OR(a,b,c) // Expands to to ((a)||(b)||(c))
```

The purpose of course is not to write an OR function.  A generalized functionality could be for more intricate applications. E.g., a macro for defining classes and functions, something to print the trace, etc.

Comment: `#define Befor (
#define After )` just `#define A(x) ((x))` .... I see no point in "before" and "after", just place them inside your `Action`. Anyway, what have you tried? `I would like to write` then write it. It is possible. If you want others to do the job for you, pay them.

Comment: I could do the OR without it, but there are other applications, e.g.,print trace, etc. I thought your comment was a bit abusive, but I changed the wording to please you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never liked the [recursive REPEAT()](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms) macro idiom - it generates horrible hour long read error messages that are.. recursive, so you don't know where the error is and it's also hard to grasp how the `OBSTRUCT(REPEAT_INDIRECT) ()` stuff works. Overall, overloading the macro on number of arguments and using an external tool (shell script or m4 preprocessor) to generate C source code is waay easier, easier to read, maintain and fix and also you can expand the macros on the tools side removing the burden of recursive expansion on C side. With that in mind, your `ITERATE` can be generated with existing preprocessor libraries, `P99_FOR` or `BOOST_FOREACH` comes to mind.

Also, typing `shift` all the time is strange - I prefer snake case. Here's a reduced example without `Before` and `After` macros with overloading the macro on number of arguments:

```
#define _in_ITERATE_0(f,b,e)           e()
#define _in_ITERATE_1(f,b,e,_1)        f(_1)
#define _in_ITERATE_2(f,b,e,_1,...)    f(_1)b()_in_ITERATE_1(f,b,e,__VA_ARGS__)
#define _in_ITERATE_3(f,b,e,_1,...)    f(_1)b()_in_ITERATE_2(f,b,e,__VA_ARGS__)
// or you could expand it instead of reusing previous one with same result:
#define _in_ITERATE_4(f,b,e,_1,_2,_3,_4)    f(_1)b()f(_2)b()f(_3)b()f(_4)
// etc.... generate
#define _in_ITERATE_N(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...)  _in_ITERATE_##N
#define ITERATE(func, between, empty, ...)  \
    _in_ITERATE_N(0,##__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)(func, between, empty, ##__VA_ARGS__)


#define _in_OR_OP(x)     (x) 
#define _in_OR_EMPTY()     1
#define _in_OR_BETWEEN()  ||
#define OR(...)   (ITERATE(_in_OR_OP, _in_OR_BETWEEN, _in_OR_EMPTY, ##__VA_ARGS__))

// Use it
OR()      // Expands to (1)
OR(a)     // Expands to ((a))
OR(a,b)   // Expands to ((a)||(b))
OR(a,b,c) // Expands to to ((a)||(b)||(c))
```

outputs:

```
(1)
((a))
((a)||(b))
((a)||(b)||(c))
```

For more examples on overloading macro on count of arguments see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761703/overloading-macro-on-number-of-arguments). I am using `##` GNU extension to remove the comma before `__VA_ARGS__` because I am used to using it - I think `__VA_OPT__(,)` should be nowadays preferred, I am not sure.