# Does C++ 23 have variadic macros?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

According to comments on [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679979/how-to-make-a-variadic-macro-variable-number-of-arguments) C99 has variadic macros, but the then-current C++ does not.

However, that was over a decade ago, and I'm interested in the new versions of C++.

Does C++ 20 or 23 have variadic macros? If not, are any stakeholders trying to get them on the agenda for future versions?

Comment: C++ has had variadic macros like C since day one.  They all come from the C preprocessor that both C and C++ use

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Comment: That said, C++11 introduced [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which should be preferred.

Comment: Not since day one, but since C++11. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Comment: It has since c++11 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike - Officially? No. C++ defines preprocessing on its own, not by simple defferal. Only C++11 offically added variadic macros.

Comment: *Does C++ 23 have variadic macros?*  Yes.  C++ has had variadic macros since C++11.

Comment: If possible try to avoid macros, C++ has (variadic) templates. So what are you trying to solve with variadic macros?