# C++ debug print to stream generates warnings

Tags: c++, stream, debug-print

I saw this debug print for c++ [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67428/1693829) but I can't comment it (I'm a newbie):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dout cout
#else
#define dout 0 && cout
#endif
```

It is used like this:

```
dout << "in foobar with x= " << x << " and y= " << y << '\n';
```

At first sight I liked it, but I compile with -Wall, so I get a lot of warnings like

> test1.cc:30:46: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Is there a way to reconcile -Wall and the stream oriented debug print?

Comment: you can use `#pragma` to disable specific warnings you are aware of

Comment: Are you suggesting a global disabling or is there a way to incorporate that in the macro?

Comment: It works in the scope of the file, IIRC

Answer (score 2):

This can be further refined, but try this as starting point:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define LOG_DEBUG( stuff ) { std::cout << stuff << std::endl; }
#else
#define LOG_DEBUG( stuff )
#endif
```

Then later in the code:

```
LOG_DEBUG( __FILE__ << " bla bla bla " << foo );
```