# Writing to Output window from a c++ called by C#

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution that is mostly C#, but has also few C++ projects.
At some point I call a c++ dll from C# code.

Is there a way to write to visual studio output window from the c++ code (for debugging purposes)?
I tried `printf` but it did not seem to have any effect...

(I am using VS 2012, .Net 4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [OutputDebugString function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to support variable arguments (like printf), you need to add a bit more code as in this answer: [How do you create a debug only function that takes a variable argument list? Like printf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240/how-do-you-create-a-debug-only-function-that-takes-a-variable-argument-list-lik)

Comment: The second link is not available. where can I find what you suggested?

Comment: @ayssa - thanks for reporting this. I've updated the answer